# form submit and check button mixed up

Tags: javascript, html

here is a code I have written:

first name and last name fields are "required" so they must not remain empty. this is what I want my "submit" button to check.

user name must be between 8 to 12 characters and it must start with a letter and it mustn't remain empty. and this is what i want my "valid" button to check.
(all 4 functions must be called with a single click on "valid" button)

but when I click on "valid" button it also checks whether first name and last name are empty or not.
how can I fix this problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function underflow() {
    var x = document.forms["regForm"]["uname"].value;
    if (x.length < 8) {
        alert("username too short");
        return false;
    }
}

function overflow() {
    var x = document.forms["regForm"]["uname"].value;
    if (x.length > 12) {
        alert("username too long");
        return false;
    }
}

function pattern() {
    var x = document.forms["regForm"]["uname"].value;
    if (x.pattern != "^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]{1,12}$") {
        alert("pattern mismatch");
        return false;
    }
}

function empty() {
    var x = document.forms["regForm"]["uname"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="regForm" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
first name: <input type="text" name="fname"  required="required"><br>
last name: <input type="text" name="lname"  required="required"><br>

username: <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname"><br>
<button onclick="underflow() overflow() pattern() empty()">valid?</button></td>

<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You do not need to enclose each function in its own `script` element. Just wrap all of your JavaScript with one `<script>`. Also, if the fields are marked as `required`, then why are you checking them again? Next, with an `onclick` event attribute that is supposed to invoke several statements, each statement must be separated from the next with a `;`. You've also got a `form.submit` event handler as well as a `submitButton.click` event handler. Do your validation in the `form.submit` only.

Comment: Lastly, if you simply use the `required` and `pattern` attributes on your input fields, no JavaScript validation would be necessary at all.

Comment: I edited the <script>s

when I click on submit button, first name and last name will be check.

but when I click "valid" button it also checks first name and last name which is something I don't want

and please if you can, answer this question. I want to have all those 4 functions called when I click "valid" button.

Comment: Read the rest of my comments. You are running your functions when you click the button and also when the form submits.

Answer (score 0):

A button will submit its wrapping form by default. Add `type="button"` attribute to the button to prevent it from submitting the form and checking the first name and last name.

Comment: thanks.it worked


but my button doesn't work. it doesn't call all the functions. but when i remove 3 out of 4 functions the remaining function will work. any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Add inside the script tag before the closing `function validate() { underflow(); overflow(); pattern(); empty(); }`

And change the button to `<button onclick="validate()">valid?</button>`